# How to change bar color based on number value in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a horizontal bar chart where I'm supposed to turn the bars slowly from yellow to red based on the horizontal value. So the greater the X value the more the bars chart get red

(I wanted to show the plot but I couldn't upload the image of it due to my low reputation)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = [3,3,4]
y = [1,2,5]
plt.barh(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something of similar, hand-made:

```
colorsValue = []
for value in x:
    if value < LOW_TRESHOLD:
        colorsValue.append('yellow')
    elif value >= HIGH_TRESHOLD:
        colorsValue.append('red')
    else:
        colorsValue.append('orange')

plt.barh(x, y, color = colorsValue)
```

where `LOW_TRESHOLD` and `HIGH_TRESHOLD` are values decided by you, as well as colors. List of matplotlib colors is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html).

This was only a minimal example to show you the syntax. Solution of Kroshtan is good as well and more general than my home-made solution, so I advice you to use his one.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array in the `color` parameter. The values of this array can be calculated using cmap from the matplotlib documentation.

```
colors = [(1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)]
my_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    'color_map', colors, N=100)
```

Then you scale the colors to the values you have:

```
rescale = lambda y: (y - np.min(y)) / (np.max(y) - np.min(y))    
plt.barh(x,y,color=my_cmap(rescale(y)))
plt.show()
```